# SSRS -> Using code function to create my query dynamically, how do I get at my data (put data into table)?

Tags: reporting-services

I am not a seasoned SSRS veteran.  I have made quite a few but they were pretty simple.

Today, I am attempting to use the Code tab of the Report Properties to perform some vb functions that will return my query in a string.  I am passing in date parameter that is used to create my dynamic query.

My problem/issue is that I do not know how to pull this information into my table.

I have seen instances where a developer calls from each individual field and it calls the code to get a specific field.  I was under the impression that I could somehow use a dataset to do this and have some documentation on this, but can't seem to find anything on the web regarding how to do this.

This is probably a pretty poorly written question, but does anyone know how to do this?

I was thinking in the Dataset Properties, I would code something like this in the expression field.

```
=Code.GetReportDetail(Parameter!InputDate.Value)
```

GetReportDetail being the starting function within my code window.

I am having difficulties how I can then pull that dataset into my table from that point though.

Any advice on this is greatly appreciated....Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details of why you need to use the embedded code to generate your query. (You know you can refer to SSRS parameters in a SQL query, right?) Sounds like you'd be better off with a different approach.

Comment: I was just having difficulties getting it to work with MDX query I was using.  Should have mentioned that I was using MDX also.  I have posted how I got this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further review, I was creating this in VS2010 for RC0 2012 SQL Server, which I should have noted above.

All you have to do is create your report by adding new item (Report).  Add your code by right clicking in the pink area and going to Report Properties and pasting your code into the code tab.

Next when you pull a table into your "add item to the report / white space"  It allows you to create your dataset.

I chose use dataset embedded in my report.  Datasource of OLE DB because I am doing MDX.  Query Type Text then in the function I pasted this. (omitting parameters for now) :

```
=Code.GetReportDetail()
```

I then filled in fields manually because it seems that dynamic query running does not pull in fields.
I was then able to reference these manually created fields via my table detail row.